# Code first migration adds addition field with underscore

Tags: c#, migration, code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a database with two tables linked.  When I run the initial migration I am getting an additional `Analysis_Id` field added even though that is not in my model.

My basic setup is that an Analysis will have a history of Checkouts over time (1 to many).  However at any one time it will only ever have 1 (represented by the CheckedOutById on Analysis table).

```
public class CheckOut
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ByUser")]
    public int ByUserId { get; set; }        
    public virtual UserProfile ByUser { get; set; }

    public int AnalysisId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AnalysisId")]
    public virtual Analysis Analysis { get; set; }

    public DateTime At { get; set; }
}

public class Analysis
{
    public Analysis()
    {
        Revisions = new Collection<AnalysisRevision>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SupplierSeasonId { get; set; }
    public virtual SupplierSeason SupplierSeason { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CheckedOutById")]
    public virtual CheckOut CheckedOutBy { get; set; }
    public int? CheckedOutById { get; set; }

    public DataState DataState { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CheckOut> CheckOuts { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<AnalysisRevision> Revisions { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SourceId")]
    public virtual AnalysisSource Source { get; set; }
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
}
```

The generated migration

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.CheckOut",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ByUserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    AnalysisId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    At = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Analysis_Id = c.Int(), // The rogue column
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Analysis", t => t.AnalysisId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.UserProfile", t => t.ByUserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Analysis", t => t.Analysis_Id)
            .Index(t => t.ByUserId)
            .Index(t => t.AnalysisId)
            .Index(t => t.Analysis_Id);
```

And the script for the Analysis table (Note the rogue Checkout_Id field)

```
                 CreateTable(
            "dbo.Analysis",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    SupplierSeasonId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CheckedOutById = c.Int(),
                    DataState = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    SourceId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.SupplierSeason", t => t.SupplierSeasonId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.CheckOut", t => t.CheckedOutById)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AnalysisSource", t => t.SourceId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.SupplierSeasonId)
            .Index(t => t.CheckedOutById)
            .Index(t => t.SourceId);
```

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework is just doing what you tell it to do. Observe that you have two relationships between `Analysis` and `CheckOut`.

First you have a one-to-one relationship and that relationship is being stored using `CheckedOutById` and `AnalysisId`.

Then you also have a one-to-many relationship because of the navigation property `CheckOuts` in `Analysis` Entity, but `CheckOut` entity no foreign key to store this relationship and Entity Framework is generating one for you.

I also found other issues, maybe you want to take a look:

- Attribute `[ForeignKey("ByUser")]` is misplaced.
- If you are using naming conventions then you don't need to use the `ForeignKey` attribute.
- Initializing navigation properties in the constructor will disable Change Tracking Proxies (and I believe that an Exception will be thrown) because you will override the collection that **EF** is creating for you.

**EDIT:**
You can use this code to set the relationships using the fluent api. I'm making some assumptions about you code but it should work. Use this in your `DbContext` class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CheckOut>().HasRequired(c => c.Analysis).WithOptional(a => a.CheckedOutBy);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Analysis>().HasMany(a => a.CheckOuts).WithRequired(c => c.AnalysisMany);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for those comments.  In regards to the one to one.  So I guess there is no way to just have the relationship from Analysis to CheckOut as essentially that is what I'm wanting without generating this extra property?

Comment: @dreza If you only want a one-to-one relationship then you should remove the navigation property `ICollection<CheckOut> CheckOuts`

Comment: I would like both.  I want Analysis to contain a list of checkouts but I also want it to contain a reference to the most recent one...

Comment: @dreza Then you need both foreign keys, those are not optional in the database schema. But you can change the name of the property if you declare it in the model and use fluent api or attributes to define the relationship

Comment: ok, so I would change the name of checkouts to something else and setup that 1 to many relationship in fluent api leaving the one to one in? Do you have an example of what I might do here?

Comment: oh, and in regards to initializing nav properties.  No exception is thrown and it appears I may still may have change tracking (not 100% on that but I also haven't noticed any problems so far).  But point taken it's probably not a good idea anyway.

Comment: @dreza see my updated answer. About initializing nav properties, I ran it in my PC and it failed. But I'm using EF5, maybe that's the reason.